# JMeter - minimal/compact version for CLI load test only

Tags: jmeter

About JMeter CLI tests,

If I need only CLI, without any GUI, what minimal files can I use?

Can I keep only bin and lib folders?

Are there jars used only in GUI that can be removed?

Current latest version size is more than 120 MB and I need to lower size to a minimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `If I need only CLI, without any GUI, what minimal files can I use?` - depending on what test elements you're using in your test, for example if you're using only [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers you will need `ApacheJMeter_http.jar` and `ApacheJMeter_core.jar` (maybe `ApacheJMeter_components.jar` if you need to use configuration elements, timers, etc.)

   So you need to analyze your test and use [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) to uninstall the components you don't need, it will reduce space requirements and make your JMeter instance faster.
2. `Can I keep only bin and lib folders?` - yes
3. Are there jars used only in GUI that can be removed? - no, according to [TestElement Contract](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html#testelement-contract) they are not separated

I think the most space consuming is [`docs` folder](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/master/xdocs) so if you need offline [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/) version you can delete it and JMeter will take twice less disk space